# how to convert an image to Base64-encoded in esp32?

Tags: esp32

i would like to convert an image to Base64-encoded in esp32 cam . already i used method under detail like this :
`ConvertBase64("D:/ok.jpg","D:/edcodedFolder");`
but not working (edcodedFolder is empty)

maybe another/right way is using method under detail :
`static String encode(const uint8_t * data, size_t length, bool doNewLines = true);`
but i dont know how to use above method .
would you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

finaly i found solution under detail that works fine

String encrypt = base64::encode(fb->buf, fb->len);